# I am trying to stop my function from displaying the same object twice when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, arrays

---

I have for quite some time now been trying to figure out how I can stop my code to print the same quote twice.

Also, when every single object in the array has been printed out, I'd like for it to reset somehow. So that you can browse through the quotes once you've gone through all of them.

**This is the essential parts of my code:**

```
document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

**The printQuote function simply contains information that's accessing information from my array:**

```
var randomObjectNumber = getRandomQuote();

var html = "<p class='quote'>"
        + quotes[randomObjectNumber].quote +
        "</p>"; 

document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML = html;
```

**One random object is displayed each time you click the eventListener:**

```
function getRandomQuote () {

var randomObjectNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length );

return randomObjectNumber;
}
```

I have some ideas on how to do this and I have tried them but without success. I tried giving each object a boolean property but I can't really seem to assign each property a boolean value without messing the printQuote function up.

I also tried assigning the object displayed to a different array but the same problem occurred there.

I feel like there is some concepts around the eventListener that I don't fully understand, because every time I try to manipulate a displayed object I just end up changing every single object.

**This is what a typical object in the array looks like by the way:**

```
{quote : "Darkness is merely the absence of light"}
```

**(I also have other properties assigned to the object but i feel like presenting them would be redundant)**

If someone could explain, or give me a hint, on how to solve this problem I've been struggling with for some time.

Some hints would be greatly appreciated!

Have a nice day.

Sebastian.

EDIT: All code: https://jsfiddle.net/fusqb7hz/

Comment: We need to see the code, can you create a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/)? One more thing how many times in your code do you have addEventListener?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fusqb7hz/

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/fusqb7hz/1/

Comment: That's it, you are calling addEventListener twice. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need:

1. Create a separate array that will store all quotes that you've already used.
2. Remove quote from initial array.
3. Check if you still have quotes in initial array, if not, get them back from backup array.

Comment: DUDE you just answered so many questions that have been bugging me for the last 48 hours. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call addEventListener twice:

```
//Let's developers create multiple eventListeners without being redundant.
function onClicking (printFunction) {
document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printFunction, false);
}
onClicking(printColor);
onClicking(printQuote);
```

by calling onClicking twice you make the click happen twice, so addEventListener is added twice, meaning one click counts as two.

Change the above code for this:

```
//Let's developers create multiple eventListeners without being redundant.
document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", function(){
  printColor();
  printQuote();
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fusqb7hz/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated. Do you happen to have any suggestion or hint on how to solve the other issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach is to shuffle your quote array and then go through them one by one.  This gives you the next "random" as yet unseen quote.  The only part I'm not keen on is this shuffler (a derivation of Fisher Yates) modifies the original quote array. You might not care about that though.

```js
// --------------------------------
// A bunch of quotes
// --------------------------------
var quotes = [];
quotes.push({quote : "Darkness is merely the absence of light"});
quotes.push({quote : "quote 2"});
quotes.push({quote : "quote 3"});
quotes.push({quote : "quote 4"});
quotes.push({quote : "quote 5"});
// --------------------------------

// --------------------------------
// Your favorite array shuffle utility
// --------------------------------
var shuffle = function(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
};
// --------------------------------

// --------------------------------
// construct a function to get a random unseen quote until
// all quotes have been seen.  Then reset...
// --------------------------------
var getQuote = (function(quotes, shuffle){
  var current = 0;

  var get = function(){
    if ( !quotes || !quotes.length ) { return ""; }
    if ( current >= quotes.length ){ current = 0; }
    if ( current === 0 ){
      console.log("randomizing quotes...");
      shuffle(quotes);
    }
    return quotes[current++].quote;
  };

  return get;
})(quotes, shuffle);
// --------------------------------

var printQuote = function(){
  document.getElementById('quote').innerText = getQuote();
};

document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>
<button id="loadQuote">get quote</button>
```